# com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: android, json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am getting 500 Internal Server Error while calling an App Engine Endpoint from android client. Everything in my code looks fine and I am really confused about this error.

Calling the Endpoint Api:

```
try {
        return myApiService.updateUserAction(userId1, userId2, action).execute().getData();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
```

UserActionEndpoint (simplest form):

```
@ApiMethod(name = "updateUserAction")
    public DefaultStringBean updateUserAction(@Named("firstUserId") String firstUserId,
                                              @Named("secondUserId") String secondUserId,
                                              @Named("action") String action) {

        DefaultStringBean response = new DefaultStringBean();
        response.setData("200");
        return response;
    }
```

and DefaultStringBean:

```
public class DefaultStringBean {

    private String result;

    public String getData() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setData(String response) {
        result = response;
    }
}
```

Why should I get this error?

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
```

More Info: I have implemented more Endpoints which return this type of data and none of them thrown this exception.

Comment: There's not enough information to answer this question. Do you see logs in your application backend? Have you tried using API Explorer to make the call?

Comment: @saiyr, I've tried in Api Explorer and it works without any errors.

Comment: That's promising. What about the logs?

Comment: @saiyr, I am running the backend on local server and as far as I know, there is no way to access logs on local server. Am I wrong?

Comment: The command line prints out logs. If you're running it in the background then you need to try running it in the foreground. If you're running locally have you configured the client to connect to localhost?